# Adding a single overlay to MapView on Android

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, android-2.2-froyo

Is it possible to add a single overlay to a MapView without having to use the `ItemizedOverlay` class which seems a bit overkill for a single overlay?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a solution for this, so ended up using `ItemizedOverlay` with one item in it.  Yet, this was about a year ago now - I haven't check if anybody found a way lately.

Comment: Seems like overkil to me, but thanks. Hopefully someone will know a way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can create a sub-class that extends `Overlay` and `override` its `draw()` and add your stuff to show an Overlay. [`Here`](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) is a complete example for the same.